# Alternative to render_qweb_pdf in odoo-14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I want to save my pdf report as attachment so I can make a zip file of some attachments from that report.

```
    pdf = self.env.ref('module_name..report_id').render_qweb_pdf(self.ids)
    b64_pdf = base64.b64encode(pdf[0])
    # save pdf as attachment
    name = "My Attachment"
    return self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
        'name': name,
        'type': 'binary',
        'datas': b64_pdf,
        'datas_fname': name + '.pdf',
        'store_fname': name,
        'res_model': self._name,
        'res_id': self.id,
        'mimetype': 'application/x-pdf'
    })
```

I get this solution for odoo version 13.0 from [HERE](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/creating-pdf-attachment-automatically-odoo-13), but it doesn't work so well in odoo version 14.0. It says that

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1733, in run
    result = action.run()
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 629, in run
    res = runner(run_self, eval_context=eval_context)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/addons/website/models/ir_actions.py", line 61, in _run_action_code_multi
    res = super(ServerAction, self)._run_action_code_multi(eval_context)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 498, in _run_action_code_multi
    safe_eval(self.code.strip(), eval_context, mode="exec", nocopy=True)  # nocopy allows to return 'action'
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 346, in safe_eval
    raise ValueError('%s: "%s" while evaluating\n%r' % (ustr(type(e)), ustr(e), expr))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/admin/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: <class 'AttributeError'>: "'ir.actions.report' object has no attribute 'render_qweb_pdf'" while evaluating
"action = env['wgs.form.1721.a1.list'].generate_attachments(env.context.get('active_ids'))"
```

I've tried similar solution from different sites, but it produces similar result to this one. Pls help. I think this is new in odoo-14. I'm new in odoo development as well, so I don't know that much

Answer (score 1):

```
pdf = self.env.ref('module_name..report_id')._render_qweb_pdf(self.ids)
```

You have to put _render_qweb_pdf like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def action_get_attachment(self):
        pdf = self.env.ref('project2.tr_cetificate_action_id')._render_qweb_pdf(self.ids)
        b64_pdf = base64.b64encode(pdf[0])
        name = "My Attachment"
        return self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
            'name': name,
            'type': 'binary',
            'datas': b64_pdf,
            # 'datas_fname': name + '.pdf',
            'store_fname': name,
            'res_model': self._name,
            'res_id': self.id,
            'mimetype': 'application/x-pdf'
        })
```

This code will work in version 14.